# EJB transaction management

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, websphere-liberty, transactional

I am trying to understand EJB transaction management. I wrote the below code and deployed in websphere liberty

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class BookRepositoryBean {

  @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/mydb")
  private DataSource dataSource;

  public void create(List<Book> books) {

  try {
    for(Book book: books) {
      Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement stmt = con.preparedStatement("insert into ....");
      stmt.setString(1, ...);
      stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
  } catch(SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

My server.xml looks something like below

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/mydb" transactional="false">
....
</dataSource>
```

I manually inserted a record in the table which has a primary key constraint and then tried running my code to persist two records where one is a duplicate record and another is a new record.

I tried with different options and observed the following

> 1. Server XML datasource: transactional=false
>      TransactionManagementType=BEAN
>      Result: 1/2 records persisted. Since there is no transaction
>      management code written, this is expected.
> 2. Server XML datasource: transactional=true
>      TransactionManagementType=CONTAINER
>      Result: 0/2 records persisted. Since transaction management is enabled
>      0 records are inserted.
> 3. Server XML datasource: transactional=false
>      TransactionManagementType=CONTAINER
>      Result: 1/2 records persisted
> 4. Server XML datasource: transactional=true
>      TransactionManagementType=BEAN
>      Result: 1/2 records persisted. I understood that, since I turned off
>      transaction management at code level, 1 record has been persisted.
> 5. Server XML datasource: transactional=true
>      Removed @Stateless and @TransactionManagement annotations
>      Result: 0/2 records persisted.

In case 3, I dont understand why 1 record is inserted. I am assuming container level transaction management will work only when enabled in code and also by enabling at container level. Am i right?

In case 5, I don't understand why 0 records have been persisted when the class is not an EJB. I always assumed that transaction management is only available with EJBs. This test has proved me wrong. Now I don't understand why should one choose EJB over a regular java class.

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding #5, by removing the annotations and having it be a normal java class, it runs under the transaction and context of the invoker.  Is the invoker another EJB with container managed transactions?

Comment: Yes the invoker is an EJB. Thanks for pointing. I will try to test it again by removing Stateless annotation on the invoker.

Comment: I removed Stateless annotation on the caller and tested. 1/2 records are persisted. Thanks for pointing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> 3. Server XML datasource: transactional=false
>      TransactionManagementType=CONTAINER
>      Result: 1/2 records persisted
>      
>      In case 3, I dont understand why 1 record is inserted. I am assuming container level transaction management will work only when enabled in code and also by enabling at container level. Am i right?

Even though the container is managing transactions in this EJB, if a resource is not able to participate in transactions (i.e. transactional=false) then each operation executes individually.  Inserting the duplicate key fails, and inserting the other key succeeds.

Comment: So, in the 5th case, will a record be persisted if I run the same code in jboss or any other application server which does not have LTE?

Comment: turns out I had case #5 incorrect.  This is not how LTCs work, so I've removed that part of my answer.